# Charles Proxy list of websites hasn't been showing up lately what should I do?

Tags: debugging, proxy, charles-proxy

Hi I have a problem with Charles Proxy not displaying the names of the websites in the structure section. I have used Charles for quite a while around two months ago and played around with the settings and used it for other purposes like coding things into online games.

However as soon as my 30 day trial ended, I downloaded an unlocker onto a different version of Charles proxy (4.6.3 version), as the unlocker is only compatible with that version of it. Upon that I installed the unlocker and located the file into the file explorer application and dragged it into programme files and placed it under the Charles lib section.

I closed Charles and started again, the same thing still happened where the list of websites didn't pop up again. This has started to annoy me and has been going on for a while. Been trying to see any Youtube videos on this problem and most of the videos about Charles aren't even about this specific problem I have. Long story short I tried resetting my computer and deleted any website links to Charles Proxy in my search history in order for the website to not recognize my computer, I tried installing different versions of Charles Proxy hoping the trial would start all over again for me. When I did all that, Charles Proxy still didn't display any of the websites that I went to.

Did I do anything wrong to mess up the system? I followed a few tutorials on how to set up Charles Proxy, following each step correctly and paying attention to the settings that can be touched and the ones that can't be touched.

Advice would be greatly appreciated thanks